# Heroku local - Stuck on "[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format"

Tags: heroku

I'm following the Heroku tutorial deploying a Python (Django) project.  I am stuck on the '[Run the app locally' section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally).

I am using windows, and when I run `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows`, I get the first message - `[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format`, and it is just stuck there.  [No further messages](https://i.gyazo.com/dc5a82e1facfb97ca821c458ea1e233e.png).

My Procfile.windows file has a single line, which reads - `web: py -3 manage.py runserver`.

Why is this stuck?

Answer (score 2):

There may not be any more messages. I get the same result and I was quite stumped for a while until I tried actually loading up the site.

My `Procfile.windows`:

`web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`

When I run `heroku localweb -f Procfile.windows`:

`[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format`

When I open up `localhost:8080` in chrome:

`[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
21:19:49 web.1   |  [29/Apr/2018 21:19:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7425
21:19:50 web.1   |  [29/Apr/2018 21:19:50] "GET /static/lang-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2217
21:19:51 web.1   |  Not Found: /favicon.ico
21:19:51 web.1   |  [29/Apr/2018 21:19:51] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2218`

Answer (score 0):

The file name should just be Procfile not Procfile.windows, Thats how it is in rails

Comment: Procfile.windows is used when running django on Heroku.  
Procfile will be used on Heroku in production, and Procfile.windows is used during local development.